# How to use a button to call a function to display text in Tkinter

Tags: user-interface, tkinter, web-scraping

I want to create a button which when pressed displays a message of the price_text variable in the get_btc function. I'm a GUI noob so just looking for some guidance apologies if there is already a post on this I've tried searching and haven't found a reliable answer.

My current code looks like this and is split in a directory like so

crypto_price--Model--scraper.py
|
GUI.py

The contents is:

Scraper.py:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime
import requests
import time
import lxml


def get_btc():

        url = requests.get("https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/quote/BTC-GBP/")
        soup = BeautifulSoup(url.text, "lxml")
        finds = soup.find_all("div", class_="D(ib) Mend(20px)")[0].find('span')

        for find in finds:
            price=find
            price_text= f"The price of BTC at {datetime.datetime.now()} is £{price}"
            print(price_text)
            time.sleep(5)


GUI.py:
from tkinter import *
from Model.scraper import get_btc

window = Tk()
window.title("BTC Price")
photo1 = PhotoImage(file="btc.png")
Label(window, image=photo1, bg="black").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=E)
PriceButton = Button(text="Btc Price", command=get_btc())
PriceButton.place(x=0, y=0)
PriceButton.pack

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ive added an answer, do let me know

Comment: To add on to what Cool Cloud said, the () on the function call does not work because the function is immediately executed. Therefore, you cannot press a button more than once and expect actual results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't call your function, it should be:

```
PriceButton = Button(text="Btc Price", command=get_btc)
```

The `()` for the function at the command has to be removed. When you use `()` your calling(invoking) the function, python runs the function as soon as it sees `()` with the function name, so remove it and the button will call the function for you each time, you press the button.

Comment: Ok so I've sorted it so the button prints the output in the terminal then created another label Label(window,bg="white",text=).grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=E) what should I put in the text of that label so that it returns the end value of the price_text in the label?

Comment: sorry about not marking earlier im new to stack overflow